# How to return to activity after sending a mail in android?

Tags: android, email, android-activity, start-activity

All working fine and the mail is also properly sending .But I cant return to the activity after sending mail.

Current screen history is false.I have used start Activity with result code also.But cant make it.

Could some one guide or provide some sample code it will be really usefull for me

```
bookByMail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {// sending mail details
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {                   
                    String mailId ="deepakmeccse26@gmail.com";
                      String sms = messageSummary.getText().toString();
                      String subject="Bottle Order";
                      Intent email = new Intent();
                      email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"bbbb@gmail.com","aaa@gmail.com"});
                      email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{"xxxx@gmail.com"});
                      email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{"xxx@gmail.com"});
                      email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                      email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sms);           
                      email.setType("sms/rfc822");   
                      //email.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);                
                     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));                                      
                                }                                           
            });         
    dialog.show();
    }   
        });
        }
```

Comment: you cannot go back to your app after sending your intent to other app.. build your sending email code by yourself using smtp

Comment: ok will try and let you know.Thanks

Comment: have you seen my answer ? where have you reached with this ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) instead of `startActivity()`. This will return to the starting `Activity` after the `Intent` action is completed. See the [**Getting a Result from an Activity**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) post for an example.

Comment: I also used that, could you please provide any sample code for StartActivityForResult().I am also searching for it.

Comment: @Deepak: have you seen the posted link ? It has an example.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, you should use `startActivityForResult()` method.

> This method starts a new activity and waits for the result code which
>   comes from new activity when new activity exits

You need to do some changes like :

```
bookByMail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {                   
        String mailId ="deepakmeccse26@gmail.com";
        String sms = messageSummary.getText().toString();
        String subject="Bottle Order";
        Intent email = new Intent();
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"bbbb@gmail.com","aaa@gmail.com"});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{"xxxx@gmail.com"});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{"xxx@gmail.com"});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sms);           
        email.setType("sms/rfc822");   
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"), 800);                                      
    }                                           
});
```

And wait for response by overriding `onActivityResult()` method :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 800) {
        //Called when returning from your email intent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my testing, the code below launches an email client and starts composing an email message. When I click Send or Discard, I am automatically returned to the activity that executed the code to launch the email client. Note that the code uses `startActivity()` and not `startActivityForResult()`.

What does *not* work using this code is returning to the activity that launched the email client using Up navigation (clicking the arrow on the left side of the action bar). And using `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()` made no difference.

```
public void onClickSendEmail(View unused) {
    String body = "App Version Code: " + BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
    body += "\nApp Version Name: " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
    body += "\nOS API Level: " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    body += "\nDevice: " + android.os.Build.DEVICE;
    body += "\nModel: " + android.os.Build.MODEL;
    body += "\nProduct: " + android.os.Build.PRODUCT;

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("plain/text");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { getString(R.string.roamfree_email_addess) });
    String userId = "fakeid";
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "RoamFree Feedback: User Id " + userId);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Email Client:"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Inside Activity onCreate Method**

```
    btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String isim = innerName.getText().toString();
            String yurtIsmi = innerYurtName.getText().toString();
            String telNo = innerTelNo.getText().toString();
            String message = " ";
            String messageTitle = isim + " Hello ";
            String messageBody = isim + " " + yurtIsmi + "\n" + " " + ulke_sehir + "\n" + " " + telNo + "\n" + " " + message;
            try {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("message/rfc822");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"samir@gmail.com"});
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, messageTitle);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, messageBody);
                // startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose an Email client :"),0);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(KayitAct.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

**receive the result** inside the same activity

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    String sam = "";
    if (requestCode  == 0) { // Activity.RESULT_OK
        Toast.makeText(KayitAct.this, "Kayıt Talebiniz Tarfımıza İletildi \nEn Kısa Sürede Dönüş Yapılacaktır", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intentGoToMenu = new Intent(KayitAct.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentGoToMenu);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        finish();
    }

}
```